# How can I smooth my hand-drawn line-art in Krita?

Tags: line-art, krita

I started learning how to draw on a tablet the other day.  I drew a kitty in *Krita*:

> [image: kitty (colored)]
> [image: kitty (line art)]
> (Adapted from [this image](https://www.peppercarrot.com/en/viewer/sketchbook-src__2018-02-06_Carrot-asking-something_by-David-Revoy.html) by David Revoy, 2018; [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/))

However, if you look carefully enough, you can see poorly drawn lines (I'm just a newbie), like these in the tail:

> [image: zooming in on the kitty's tail, we can see lines which are not particularly straight]

Now I could fix them by manually editing them on my tablet (which is a bit tedious), or I could just consider these imperfections as part of the art itself.  But I'm wondering if there are computational means in Krita to make such lines look smoother (as if I drew it in a single stroke) with minimal effort.

**Question**: How can I smooth my hand-drawn line-art in Krita?

Comment: Not after they have been drawn as raster images. Its a bit different things for vectors since they are the path its easy to change. But yes Krita can smooth  while you are drawing, in the brush options set the smoothing to weighted smoothing and adjust the distance untill you are satisfied bigger values get smoother curve but feedback is delayed.

Comment: You may use autosmooth when you draw. It's available in all advanced drawing programs. Making thin curves smooth when they are already a part of a bitmap layer needs something much more clever than what's available in drawing programs. Most of us want to fix some curves afterwards. Drawing curves as vector paths which stay as separate editable items allows such edits easily. Another freebie named  Inkscape may be useful to you as a flexible vector drawing platform.

Comment: (continued) In the next image the blue curve is drawn in Inkscape with the freeform Bezier curve tool i.e. the Pencil with no smoothing. The drawing stylus in my hand was the mouse. The red curve is about the same movement with the mouse, but smoothing is turned to 35%  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkaW4.png The red one has substantially less nodes as the next image shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb0gR.png In Inkscape smoothing doesn't cause harmful delay. The smoothed curve is much easier to edit afterwards.

Comment: Realize the line vocabulary is often a **good** thing. I would say you shouldn't "smooth" anything, but rather make the lack of smoothness work *for* you. Variations in thickness, path orientation, etc offer a *much* more dynamic end result. Unless, of course, you want your work to all *look* computer generated.

Comment: If you want smoother lines and curves in Krita, it's probably better to add a vector layer, and use the Bézier tool instead. [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/huIZsq6). If you are going to use the Bézier tool, it's actually easier to use with a mouse rather than a graphics tablet.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this in Krita.

**Method one**, use the Weighted brush smoothing option in the tool options, there also a Stabilizer option - try both options. Adjust the Distance slider to increase the weight/stabilization effect.  Obviously this method won't work on lines you have already painted - you'd need to adjust the settings before painting

[image]

**Method two**, add a vector layer and use the Bézier tool. This is useful if you need to adjust the curves afterwards, since the anchors and handles are editable.

[image]